# Safe Mode with Networking

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, internet-connection, safe-mode

In my Notebook Dell Vostro 3590, the mounted wireless card is Qualcomm QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Adapter, O.S. Windows 10 PRO x64.

Although the driver updated to the latest version is installed, 12.0.0.953, wifi networks are not detected in Safe Mode with Networking.

In 'Device Manager', the card is marked with a yellow triangle with an exclamation point, and shows **error code 37**.

In this mode, I can only connect with the Ethernet cable, but the sockets are not close to my station.

I would think some solution with Regedit modifications, CMD commands...

With other computers, I have succeeded. It is with the PC that I have been using lately that for the first time I notice this lack. Obviously, I'm referring to SafeMode with Network, not Minimal.

Comment: With other computers, I have succeeded.
It is with the PC that I have been using lately that for the first time I notice this lack. Obviously, I'm referring to SafeMode with Network, not Minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Safe Mode cannot connect using Wireless Networking. That is because too few drivers are loaded.

Please see:

[Safe Mode no Wireless](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/cannot-connect-to-wifi-while-in-safe-mode-with/25f0fa9f-c9bb-4d24-a60c-31952e46d668)

> ...  it is not possible to connect to the internet through Wifi in
> Safe Mode with Networking. This is so because in Safe Mode, the
> computer uses minimal drivers that are needed for the system to run.
> Try to connect directly through the Ethernet cable and check if it
> works.

Comment: With other computers, I have succeeded. It is with the PC that I have been using lately that for the first time I notice this lack. Obviously, I'm referring to SafeMode with Network, not Minimal

Comment: It may depend on the wireless. For most wireless it won't work and that is what is happening here.